# How to use the buttons outside the constructor?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jbutton

I'm trying to create a slide puzzle in java. I created an array of 9 buttons (3x3) in the constructor. Now i want the buttons to either slide (swap positions with the empty text button), or i'll just swap the texts. But with the current code, I'm getting a Null Pointer Exception at run-time when I click on a button. I think its because the button objects i created in the constructor are not accessible in the function actionPerformed. How do I access the buttons in the function?

```
package game1;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Shuffle implements ActionListener
{
    JFrame f;
    JButton b[][];

    public Shuffle()
    {
        int i,j;
        f=new JFrame("Shuffle");
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        f.setVisible(true);

        JButton b[][]=new JButton[3][3];

        /*  
        for(int i=0;i<button.length;i++)
        {
            button[i] = new JButton();
            button[i].setText(Integer.toString(i+1));
        } 
        */
        int t=1;
        for (i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                if(i==2 && j==2)
                {
                    b[i][j]=new JButton();
                    f.add(b[i][j]);
                    t=t+1;                  
                }
                else
                {
                    b[i][j]=new JButton(""+t+"");
                    f.add(b[i][j]);
                    t=t+1;
                }
            }
        }
        for (i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                b[i][j].addActionListener(this);                    
            }
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        int x,y;
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                if(e.getSource()==b[i][j])
                {
                    x=i;y=j;
                    System.out.println(x+" "+y);
                }                   
            }
        }   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new Shuffle();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared a local variable `b` in the constructor, which hides the field `b`.  Don't do this.  Instead of

```
JButton b[][] = new JButton[3][3];
```

just write

```
b = new JButton[3][3];
```

which will assign the array to the field, instead of to a local variable.

Comment: Thanks so much. I always have a problem initializing arrays dammit! I don't know which answer to accept! they all are correct!

Answer (score 2):

Change your  button init from this:

```
JButton b[][]=new JButton[3][3];
```

to this:

```
b=new JButton[3][3];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! i dont know which answer to accept. they all are correct!

Answer (score 0):

**Try This code**

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


class Shuffle implements ActionListener {

JFrame f;
JButton b[][]=new JButton[3][3]; //This is where I changed the code

public Shuffle() {
    int i, j;
    f = new JFrame("Shuffle");
    f.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
    f.setVisible(true);



    //JButton b[][] = new JButton[3][3];   //This is where I changed the code
    /*  for(int i=0;i<button.length;i++){
     button[i] = new JButton();
     button[i].setText(Integer.toString(i+1));
     } */
    int t = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (i == 2 && j == 2) {
                b[i][j] = new JButton();
                f.add(b[i][j]);
                t = t + 1;

            } else {
                b[i][j] = new JButton("" + t + "");
                f.add(b[i][j]);
                t = t + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            b[i][j].addActionListener(this);

        }
    }

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println(""+e.getSource());
    int x, y;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (e.getSource() == b[i][j]) {
                x = i;
                y = j;
                System.out.println(x + " " + y);
            }

        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Shuffle();

}
```

}

**Resason for error** 
inside the constructor, you have created another local variable `b[][]`. You have assigned the 2D array. You don't need to create another variable as there is an attribute is created already. so initialize it.

there is another way of doing this. That is initializing attribute `b[][]` inside the constructor. Then your attribute initializion is not needed and 
following statement should be added inside the constructor method

`b[][] = new JButton[3][3];`

Comment: Thank you so much! All answers are correct! Don't know which one to accept as the correct answer.